# How to handle String.parse<_> ParseIntError [rust]

Tags: rust

I finished converting the Rust books guessing game example to an Iced GUI application and wanted to handle error handling for the input from the user.

I have a String trying to convert to an i32 and am not sure how to handle the error if the user puts a String in the text_input or just hits return. I figured out a simple solution of:

```
self.hidden_compare = self.user_guess_text.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0);
```

Rather than having self.hidden_compare default to 0. I would rather have self.user_guess_text default to a String I have set to earlier in the application and am unsure of how to accomplish this still being fairly new.

Edit: Full function added for clarification.

```
fn update(&mut self, message: Message) -> Command<Message> {
    match message {
        Message::BtnGuessNow => {
            self.hidden_compare = self.user_guess_text.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0);

            if self.hidden_value == self.hidden_compare {
                self.label_compare = String::from("A WINNER!");
                self.number_ofguesses.push(self.hidden_compare.to_string() + ", A WINNER!");
            } 
            else if self.hidden_value > self.hidden_compare {
                self.label_compare = String::from("Too Low");
                self.number_ofguesses.push(self.hidden_compare.to_string() + ", Too Low!");
            } 
            else if self.hidden_value < self.hidden_compare {
                self.label_compare = String::from("Too Big");
                self.number_ofguesses.push(self.hidden_compare.to_string()+ ", Too Big!");
            }
            self.user_guess_text = "".to_string();
            Command::none()
        }
        Message::UserInputValueUpdate(x) => {
            self.user_guess_text = x;
            Command::none()
        }
    }
```

and a relevant function that handles the Vec output:

```
fn guess_output_calc(&self) -> String {
    let mut tempoutput = String::new();

    for (i, x) in self.number_ofguesses.iter().enumerate().skip(1) {

        let guessfmt = String::from(format!("Guess# {} Was: {}\n", i, x));
        tempoutput.push_str(&guessfmt);

    };

    return
```

Comment: By "guessing game", I assume you mean [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html)? Anyhow, how to set a default string for the number input depends on whatever Iced code and setup you have, and you're showing none of that, so I don't think your question is answerable as it is right now. Also, having a default string does not prevent the user from inputting something that can't be parsed as a number, so you will still need handling for that.

Comment: As a general advice, in Rust, if you don't know how to handle an error (and want to produce clean code), it's a hint that you should *not* handle the error there. Instead, the function should return a type like `Result<T, U>` or `Option<T>` to signify that this function doesn't want to handle the error, and propagate the error with `?`.

Comment: @Caesar I have updated the post to show the full function. The entire application is finished its just this one thing bugging me and unwrap_or works Its just that I have a Vector that enumerates out your past guesses in a text field and its possible to spam text by just hitting return

Comment: Still not clear to me what you want to do, the code is still incomplete. Regardless, you can `match` on the result of `.parse()` if you want to control exactly what happens when it is parsed correctly or incorrectly: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3304bfb2d69b466ef93ee81eeac3cbca)

Comment: @j4ckkn1fe If you don't want your list of past guesses to be cluttered, store them as a list of `i32` **after** you parsed them. Don't store them as strings if you want to ignore everything that's not an `i32` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I would rather have self.user_guess_text default to a String

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with that, but I interpret this as "I want to set the `self.user_guess_text` variable to a specific value if it can't be converted to an integer". If this is wrong, then please update your question.

This is how I would approach this (simplified):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut user_guess_text = " a ";

    match user_guess_text.trim().parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(value) => {
            println!("Parsed to value: {}", value);
        }
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Unable to parse. Resetting variable.");
            user_guess_text = "fallback text!";
        }
    }

    println!("user_guess_text: {}", user_guess_text);
}
```

```
Unable to parse. Resetting variable.
user_guess_text: default text!
```